# Cannot remove spelling error highlight from lowercase "vim"

Tags: neovim, spell-checking

The word "vim" is flagged as a spelling error in my documents. If I capitalize it, the error goes away.

I don't want to capitalize "vim". Adding it to dictionary with `zG` or `zg`  does not help.

**UPDATE**

OK, I've discovered this word was somehow flagged as a "rare" word. How do I remove that designation? I'm not using any rare word list as far as I know. There's none in .vim/spell.

**UPDATE 2**

If I remove my spell dir, "vim" is still getting flagged as rare. Where could the designation as "rare" be coming from?

**UPDATE 3**

OK, this is officially driving me crazy. I moved the spell directory and did vim -u NONE and it **still* shows up as a rare word.

**UPDATE 4**

OK, tracked this down to neovim. I don't know why, but the `en.utf-8.spl` file is in the `/usr/local/share/nvim/runtime/spell` directory is getting loaded. How do I make changes to this file?

**UPDATE 5**

OK, so I ended up copying over the `en.utf-8.spl` from the vim install into neovim. But if someone could explain exactly what was happening, I'd appreciate it. How did this word get marked as flagged in the neovim spell file in the first place?

Comment: I don't think this is getting generated from spell check. Something else is generating it.

Comment: Actually, it is getting generated by spell check. When I turn spell check off, it's gone.

Comment: You can use `:spelldump` to see the dictionaries Vim uses. `vim/?` seems to be listed, so that's expected (`/?` marks as "rare"). I'm not sure how to override this from the local file though; that part doesn't seem to work 

Answer (score 0):

Check if this is caused by 'vim' is being used at the beginning of a sentence.
In my tests on vim 8.* only the first 'vim' of "vim vim vim" is flagged as a spelling error.